# Аутентификация в firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

При попытке пользователя зайти, используя логин и пароль, перекидывает на страницу регистрации, при этом никаких ошибок не всплывает.
При этом регистрация работает, данные пользователя в бд заносятся и отображаются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код логин активити:

```
EditText mEmail, mPassword;
Button mLoginBtn;
TextView mCreateBtn;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);
    mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    mCreateBtn = findViewById(R.id.CreateBtn);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //пользователь заходит

    fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             Toast.makeText(Login.this, "User created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
         }
         else {
             Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error occurred!" + Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });

    });
                mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class)));
```

код регистр активити:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mFullName = findViewById(R.id.fullName);
    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);
    mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.RegisterBtn);
    mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null ) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }


    mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                mEmail.setError("Something wrong with email...");
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                mPassword.setError("Your password if required!");
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 6) {
                mPassword.setError("Password is too short! It have to be > 6 simbols!");
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //регистрация пользователя ёпт

            fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error occurred!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

                mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
                    }
                });
```

в мейне только кнопка выхода, больше ничего нет:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void logout (View view)
{
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Судя по вашему коду - то что вы описываете не должно происходить. Возможно, вы код неправильно в вопрос скопировали? У вас немного форматирование сбито, возомжно какие-то скобки перепутались/потерялись. Попробуйте отформатировать код, поправив, хотя бы, отступы и отредактировать вопрос - возможно что-то сможем увидеть, если код станет более читаемым.

Comment: код скопировал верно, со скобками в самой иде всё хорошо и нигде ничего не подчёркивается, с этим проблем нет.
вот именно что приложение запускается, данные можно ввести, но как только жмёшь "войти" - кидает не на мейн активити, а на страницу регистрации, при этом если зарегистрироваться, затем выйти и попытаться снова войти - приложение крашится.

Comment: Код у вас всё же, как минимум не выровнен, что может свидетельствовать либо о том, что вы не в IDE код пишете (и/или не пользуетесь форматированием оного) или не получилось правильно код в редактор кода вставить. Например `fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` явно не выровнен как надо. Это вполне может быть причиной проблемы - лишняя скобка закрыла раньше чем надо инструкцию и у вас порядок выполнения не такой, какой вы ожидаете. Если почему-то причина не в этом, то надо больше информации - какие и в каком порядке у вас активити запускаются, какие ошибки есть в логах-без лога ошибки сложно помочь

Comment: понял, на будущее учту)
а по проблеме: я устал и переписал авторизацию через отдельный метод в слушателе кнопки (извиняюсь, если криво выразился, новичок совсем), и после этого всё заработало, ничего не крашится, всё отлично. я так и не понял, как так. магия.

Comment: Наверное таки скобки где-то не те были) Если git-ом пользовались, то можно по истории оного посмотреть какие изменения решили проблему. Но это только если вы правильно git-ом пользовались)